# Intellij IDEA cannot evaluate Groovy expression

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea

Sometimes Idea cannot evaluate Groovy expression and rises an error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Invalid method`. You can check it on the screen - experiment variable exists and it should be displayed...[image]
What's the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: Please file this to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard and provide some steps to reproduce there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be in your object's toString method which debugger uses.